# Why Flutter iOS build failed?

Tags: ios, firebase, flutter, flutter-ios

I have successfully build an android application and now I am building iOS application using flutter. It was everything file for the first time But I am getting this error after restarting my vscode. Can anyone help me to solve below issue? I have included Pod file code and debug output down below.

```
#platform :ios, '9.0'


ENV['COCOAPODS_DISABLE_STATS'] = 'true'

project 'Runner', {
  'Debug' => :debug,
  'Profile' => :release,
  'Release' => :release,
}

def flutter_root
  generated_xcode_build_settings_path = File.expand_path(File.join('..', 'Flutter', 'Generated.xcconfig'), __FILE__)
  unless File.exist?(generated_xcode_build_settings_path)
    raise "#{generated_xcode_build_settings_path} must exist. If you're running pod install manually, make sure flutter pub get is executed first"
  end

  File.foreach(generated_xcode_build_settings_path) do |line|
    matches = line.match(/FLUTTER_ROOT\=(.*)/)
    return matches[1].strip if matches
  end
  raise "FLUTTER_ROOT not found in #{generated_xcode_build_settings_path}. Try deleting Generated.xcconfig, then run flutter pub get"
end

require File.expand_path(File.join('packages', 'flutter_tools', 'bin', 'podhelper'), flutter_root)

flutter_ios_podfile_setup

target 'Runner' do
  use_frameworks!
  use_modular_headers!

  flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))
end

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
  end
end
```

**Debug Output**

```
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 12 Pro Max in debug mode...
lib/main.dart:1
CocoaPods' output:
↳
      Preparing
    Analyzing dependencies
    Inspecting targets to integrate
      Using `ARCHS` setting to build architectures of target `Pods-Runner`: (``)
    Finding Podfile changes
      A store_redirect
      A stripe_payment
      - Flutter
      - cloud_firestore
      - connectivity
      - firebase_analytics
      - firebase_auth
      - firebase_core
      - firebase_messaging
      - firebase_storage
      - flutter_facebook_login
      - google_sign_in
      - image_picker
      - purchases_flutter
      - shared_preferences
      - url_launcher
    Fetching external sources
    -> Fetching podspec for `Flutter` from `Flutter`
    -> Fetching podspec for `cloud_firestore` from `.symlinks/plugins/cloud_firestore/ios`
    -> Fetching podspec for `connectivity` from `.symlinks/plugins/connectivity/ios`
-> Fetching podspec for `firebase_analytics` from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_analytics/ios`
    -> Fetching podspec for `firebase_auth` from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_auth/ios`
    -> Fetching podspec for `firebase_core` from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_core/ios`
    -> Fetching podspec for `firebase_messaging` from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_messaging/ios`
    -> Fetching podspec for `firebase_storage` from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_storage/ios`
    -> Fetching podspec for `flutter_facebook_login` from `.symlinks/plugins/flutter_facebook_login/ios`
    -> Fetching podspec for `google_sign_in` from `.symlinks/plugins/google_sign_in/ios`
    -> Fetching podspec for `image_picker` from `.symlinks/plugins/image_picker/ios`
    -> Fetching podspec for `purchases_flutter` from `.symlinks/plugins/purchases_flutter/ios`
    -> Fetching podspec for `shared_preferences` from `.symlinks/plugins/shared_preferences/ios`
    -> Fetching podspec for `store_redirect` from `.symlinks/plugins/store_redirect/ios`
    -> Fetching podspec for `stripe_payment` from `.symlinks/plugins/stripe_payment/ios`
    -> Fetching podspec for `url_launcher` from `.symlinks/plugins/url_launcher/ios`
    Resolving dependencies of `Podfile`
CDN: trunk Relative path: CocoaPods-version.yml exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: all_pods_versions_0_3_5.txt exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/7.4.0/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
2
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/6.34.0/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: all_pods_versions_c_7_9.txt exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/c/7/9/Reachability/3.2/Reachability.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
4
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/6.34.0/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: all_pods_versions_9_b_5.txt exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/9/b/5/FBSDKCoreKit/9.0.0/FBSDKCoreKit.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: all_pods_versions_b_3_c.txt exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/b/3/c/FBSDKLoginKit/9.0.0/FBSDKLoginKit.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.6.6/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:182:in `resolve'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.6.6/lib/molinillo/resolver.rb:43:in `resolve'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:94:in `resolve'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:1074:in `block in resolve_dependencies'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:1072:in `resolve_dependencies'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:124:in `analyze'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:414:in `analyze'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:239:in `block in resolve_dependencies'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:238:in `resolve_dependencies'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:160:in `install!'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/command/install.rb:52:in `run'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in `run'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
    /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `load'
    /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
Error output from CocoaPods:
↳
    [!] Automatically assigning platform `iOS` with version `9.0` on target `Runner` because no platform was specified. Please specify a platform for this target in your Podfile. See `https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#platform`.
Error running pod install
Error launching application on iPhone 12 Pro Max.
Exited (sigterm)
```

Comment: This is full output from build?

Comment: @fartem sorry for not providing full debug code. now edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the error message, the `platform` property is missing from your Podfile.
To fix it, edit your app's Podfile, and add this line:
`platform :ios, '10.0'`
You can define different iOS version as well.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
post_install do |pi|
    pi.pods_project.targets.each do |t|
      t.build_configurations.each do |config|
        config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '9.0'
      end
    end
end
```

Comment: In what???  Some more information would be helpful.

Comment: @rickb this code is usually located in `./ios/Podfile`